# Most general types in Haskell and defining them

Tags: haskell

Hello I have a problem with some of my uni Haskell exercises concerning types.  I can define types for functions like (*), map etc. but the problem appears when I must define the type of:

```
f 7 (g 'a')
```

How I start with this? I know we should use some most general unifier but I didn't find anything about it on the Internet?

Further more there is another task to find **most general type** taking into account possible classes of types.

> - foldl (++)
> - square (f x)
> - g for function:
>
>   - g [ ] = Nothing
>   - g [x] = Just x
>   - g (x:y:l) = if x < y then Just x else Just y

What is most general type here? What does it mean in Haskell and what should be done here?
I would be grateful for any explanations. This is not any homework just preparation for exam, any help would be more than welcome.

Comment: One question at a time.

Comment: There are entire bookswritten with the purpose of answering this question ([TAPL](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) is an especially approachable choice). Expecting a StackOverflow-sized post to cover all the relevant material is unreasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with explicit parentheses:

```
f 7 (g 'a') == (f 7) (g 'a')
```

Knowing that `7 :: Num a => a` and `'a' :: Char`, it's immediately clear that

```
f :: Num a => a -> b
g :: Char -> c
```

for some unconstrained types `b` and `c`. However, we also know that `b` is a function type, because the return value of `f` is applied to the return value of `g`. Further, we know the return value of `g` has type `c`. So we can refine our guess for what `b` must be:

```
f :: Num a => a -> (c -> d)  -- parentheses are redundant
g :: Char -> c
```

There's not much else you can do at this point, other than make the following observations:

```
f 7 :: c -> d
g 'a' :: c
f 7 (g 'a') :: d
```